# sed - replace the whole line matching pattern & using an other delimiter

Tags: sed

given a config file like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "newspaper_project.a_string_which_need_to_be_changed"
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I'm able to replace "a_string_which_need_to_be_changed" with the following `sed` command:

```
sed -i '/DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE/c\    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "newspaper_project.the_new_string"' <PATH_TO_THE_ABOVE_CONFIG_FILE>
```

This will replace **the whole line** that contain `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` with   `os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "newspaper_project.the_new_string"`.

Now I would like to parametrize "the_new_string" into a variable of the script, so

```
#!/bin/bash
#=============================================================
SETTINGSPY="a_fresh_new_string"
#=============================================================
sed -i "s#DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE#c\os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = newspaper_project.\$SETTINGSPY" <PATH_TO_THE_ABOVE_CONFIG_FILE>
```

But this does not work, because I had to change the delimiter to something different than the default `'\'` this way I could escape the `'$'` of variable, but this does not replace the whole line but only the pattern match,  resulting into an output like this:

```
os.environ["    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "newspaper_project.a_fresh_new_string"] = "newspaper_project.a_string_which_need_to_be_changed"
```

So finnally the question is, how to use a non default delimiter character and also replace the whole line?

I would really avoid some solution like

```
sed -i "6s/.*/    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = $SETTINGSPY_RELPATH/" <PATH_TO_THE_ABOVE_CONFIG_FILE>
```

which works - of course - but it will always replace the line Nr. 6, and if one day the config file grows the script will get broken

Comment: Did you ever get a chance to review the answer below?

Comment: I'll very soon i'll not forget it, many thanks for your answer, I've just putted that project in stand by i ll take it back soon : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem comes down to how to use a variable inside the `sed` expression within single quotes but still expand the variable. You don't necessarily have to deal with another delimit character but just do selective quote of the variable part alone in double quotes and get away with using `'..'` for the whole script as

```
sed -i '/DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE/c\    os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "newspaper_project.'"$SETTINGSPY"'"'
```

Notice the variable wrapped in double quotes as `'"$SETTINGSPY"'`, the quote removal starts from the inner level. So the inner double quote expands the value of the variable and the outer single quote just preserves the expanded value and appends the expanded value with the rest of the string.

Comment: And finally at the end I returned on this issue, many thanks for your perfect answer it helped me a lot to perfectionate the deploy script : )